# Using GEOquery and SAM/Siggenes in R

Tags: r, bioconductor

I very recently started learning R as a result of a need and so far, so good, I think. But I'm still in the very early stages. I am however faced with this major urgent challenge in R that I will greatly appreciate some help with. My programming skills are quite obviously amateur and will most definitely accept any help I can get. Here goes:

1. To create a list of datasets (gdslist) to be retrieved from the GEO
   database using the GEOquery package
2. To convert the gdslist items (gdsid) to expression data. That is,
   data that can work with my analysis. For this, a GDS2eSet function
   does the work fine.
3. To read in this converted expression data in a way that a
   class/levels file (.cls) can be created. The GDS3715 dataset for
   example, has 3 levels – insulin resistant, insulin sensitive and
   diabetic. Sometimes, the datasets are as straightforward as that. But
   other times, like in this case, the levels will be 6 for analysis
   purposes, because although there are phenotypically 3 levels, they
   have been divided into treated and untreated groups. There is often an
   added “agent” column in such cases. Each class/level needs to be
   assigned a numerical number (0,1,2...). That’s pretty much the general
   format of a .cls file.
4. To run a Siggenes/SAM analysis (also a package in R), two files are
   needed for each dataset: an expression file (the converted file from 2
   above) and the accompanying cluster file (from 3).
5. To be able to run this process for the gdslist items in a kind of
   loop and have my data stored in a specified directory.

I can currently only get to step 2. I think step 3 is the crux of the challenge...

Many thanks in anticipation.

Script so far:

```
> gdslist = c('GDS3715','GDS3716','GDS3717'...)#up to perhaps 100 datasets
> analysisfunc = function(gdsid) {
    gdsdat = getGEO(gdsid,destdir=".")
    gdseset = GDS2eSet(gdsdat)
    pData(gdseset)$disease.state #Needed assignment, etc...Step 3 stuff ;Siggenes/SAM can perhaps be done here
    return(sprintf("Results from %s should be here",gdsid))
  }
> resultlist = sapply(gdslist,analysisfunc) #loop function
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of your analysis, but I often find is easy to work with a single file - get your analysis steps down, then abstract that to work with a list of files all at once. Can you perform your needed analysis for a single file?

Comment: `library(siggenes); ?sam` says that `res = sam(gdseset, gdseset$disease.state)` will take you through to step 5. Use a `for` loop if the main goal is a side effect (output of `res` to a file).

Comment: @Chase; @MartinMorgan. Thanks a bunch, Chase and Martin. With the code I included in my post, I haven't been able to achieve the wanted results with one. But thanks for the advice. I wanted to try out 'res = sam(gdseset, gdseset$disease.state)' before I responded but my internet connection is acting up a bit at the moment but I wanted to acknowledge the input and say thank you. I'll update the post when I do try out that code hopefully in the next few hours.

Comment: @Avoks.  No problem. As you can see, it makes your question much easier to read.  You can do this yourself by using the `{}` button in the question editor.

Comment: @Andrie. Yes, it really does. Noted. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinM. Thanks. That's major progress relative to what I had previously done. A dataset like GDS3715, for example, has sub-levels(agents). E.g. a level, insulin resistant, is divided into treated and untreated samples. Running `res = sam(gdseset, gdseset$agent)` understandably groups everything into 2 classes, treated and untreated, which doesn't make much sense, to me anyway. And using `res = sam(gdseset, gdseset$disease.state$agent)` doesn't work. Is there a way to possibly identify, correctly assign and pair up such data when the script comes across it? Thanks again.

Comment: @Avoks this is outside StackOverflow; you want to perform a two-way ANOVA, which `sam()` doesn't support. There's great advice on the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) mailing list, where you'll probably be pointed to [limma](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html) and it's excellent vignette. Your experiments have all sorts of different  designs, and it's unlikely that you can write a loop that accommodates all of them. Also your intuition that the design imposed by sam "doesn't make much sense" is on target; likely you want to talk with a local statistician.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all the gds datasets.

```
 GEOSAM.analysis <- function( gdsid, destdir = getwd() ) {
       require( 'GEOquery' )
       require( 'siggenes' )
       ## test if gdsid is gdsid
       if( length(grep('GDS', gdsid)) == 0 ){
        stop()
       }
       gdsdat = getGEO( gdsid, destdir = destdir )
       gdseset = GDS2eSet( gdsdat )
       gdseset.pData <- pData( gdseset )
       gds.factors <- names( gdseset.pData )
       gds.factors[gds.factors == 'sample'] <- NA
       gds.factors[gds.factors == 'description'] <- NA
       gds.factors <- gds.factors[!is.na( gds.factors )]
       cl.list <- sapply( gdseset.pData[gds.factors], as.character)
       cl.list <- factor( apply( cl.list, 1, function(x){ paste( x , collapse = '-' )} ) )
       if( length( levels ( cl.list ) ) == 2 ){
        levels( cl.list ) <- 0:length( levels( cl.list ) )
       } else {
        levels( cl.list ) <- 1:length( levels( cl.list ) )
       }
       sam.gds <- sam( gdseset, cl.list )
       results.file <- file.path( destdir, paste( gdsid, '.sam.gds.rdata', sep =''  ) )
       save( sam.gds, file = results.file )
       return( sprintf( "Results from %s are saved in '%s'. These can be loaded by 'load('%s')'.",gdsid, results.file, results.file ) )
  }

  gdslist = c('GDS3715', 'GDS3716', 'GDS3717')
  resultlist = sapply(gdslist, GEOSAM.analysis)  
  print(resultlist)
```